# Modern C++. Return data structure from working thread continuing its execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I need to launch working thread, perform some initialization, return data structure as initialization result and continue thread execution. What is the best (or possible) code to achieve this using modern c++ features only? Note, launched thread should continue its execution (thread does not terminated as usual). Unfortunately, most solutions assume worker thread termination.

Pseudo code:

```
// Executes in WorkerThread context 
void SomeClass::Worker_treadfun_with_init()
{
    // 1. Initialization calls...
    // 2. Pass/signal initialization results to caller
    // 3. Continue execution of WorkerThread    
}

// Executes in CallerThread context
void SomeClass::Caller()  
{
    // 1. Create WorkerThread with SomeClass::Worker_treadfun_with_init()" thread function
    // 2. Sleep thread for some initialization results 
    // 3. Grab results
    // 3. Continue execution of CallerThread
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for [std::future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pointer or reference to the data structure with the answer in it, and std::condition_variable to let you know when the answer has been computed:

```
#include <iostream>           
#include <thread>             
#include <mutex>              
#include <condition_variable> 

#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> g_my_answer;
std::mutex g_mtx;
std::condition_variable g_cv;
bool g_ready = false;


void Worker_treadfun_with_init()
{
  //Do your initialization here
  {
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck( g_mtx );
     for( double val = 0; val < 10; val += 0.3 )
       g_my_answer.push_back( val );

     g_ready = true;
     lck.unlock();
     g_cv.notify_one();
  }

  //Keep doing your other work..., here we'll just sleep
  for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(1) );
  }
}

void Caller()  
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(g_mtx);

  std::thread worker_thread = std::thread( Worker_treadfun_with_init );

  //Calling wait will cause current thread to sleep until g_cv.notify_one() is called.
  g_cv.wait( lck, [&g_ready](){ return g_ready; } ); 

  //Print out the answer as the worker thread continues doing its work
  for( auto val : g_my_answer )
    std::cout << val << std::endl;

  //Unlock mutex (or better yet have unique_lock go out of scope)
  // incase worker thread needs to lock again to finish
  lck.unlock();  

  //...

  //Make sure to join the worker thread some time later on.
  worker_thread.join();
}
```

Of course in actual code you wouldnt use global variables, and instead pass them by pointer or reference (or as member variables of `SomeClass`) to the worker function, but you get the point.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Unlocking after accessing the shared resources in the main thread is good practice, and required if the worker thread will need to take the lock at any point in the future; edited example code.

Comment: Both locks have calls to `unlock` that could be avoided by just changing the scope of the `unique_lock` object. It's a style issue and doesn't affect the correctness or performance of the code, but I prefer not to see calls to `unlock` where they can easily be avoided by adjusting the scope of the lock holder and letting RAII do its job.

Answer (score 0):

I think std::future meets your requirements.

```
// Executes in WorkerThread context 
void SomeClass::Worker_treadfun_with_init(std::promise<Result> &pro)
{
    // 1. Initialization calls...
    // 2. Pass/signal initialization results to caller
    pro.set_value(yourInitResult);
    // 3. Continue execution of WorkerThread    
}

// Executes in CallerThread context
void SomeClass::Caller()  
{
    // 1. Create WorkerThread with SomeClass::Worker_treadfun_with_init()" thread function
    std::promise<Result> pro;
    auto f=pro.get_future();
    std::thread([this,&pro](){Worker_treadfun_with_init(pro);}).detach();
    auto result=f.get();
    // 3. Grab results
    // 3. Continue execution of CallerThread
}
```